# Bracket parse error on if statement

Tags: syntax-error, php, brackets

Trying to put some slightly tricky form validation (in this instance for checkboxes) in relation to a sign up form for a tennis tournament

```
<?php 
if ( ( isset($_POST['ms'])&&isset($_POST['ws']) )
        || (isset($_POST['mc'])&&isset($_POST['ws']))
        || (isset($_POST['md'])&&isset($_POST['ws']))
        || (isset($_POST['ms'])&&isset($_POST['wc']))
        || (isset($_POST['ms'])&&isset($_POST['wd']))
        || (isset($_POST['mc'])&&isset($_POST['wc']))
        || (isset($_POST['mc'])&&isset($_POST['wd']))
        || (isset($_POST['md'])&&isset($_POST['wd']))
    ){
      $error_message .=('You can only play as one sex! <br />');
  }


if ( (isset($_POST['mc'])&&isset($_POST['md']) ) { //***
  $error_message .=('You cannot play in both the cadet tournament and mens doubles <br />');
  }
```

However, this causes a parse error for the line with the three asterisks.

> unexpected '{'

Presumably I have done something wrong, not in the use of curly brackets, but rather round brackets... but I cannot see where..

Comment: Add indentation and you'll better see what's missing.

Comment: remove one '(' from the begining of if statement.

Comment: Not to dodge your question but I'd highly recommend making your code a lot cleaner by using a [switch statement](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_switch.asp) and separating all these different `isset` in different cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a closing-bracket in your second `if` statement, use:

```
if ((isset($_POST['mc']) && isset($_POST['md'])))
```

In future I'd suggest counting your opening and closing brackets in complex statements to make sure they're balanced.

Comment: I would say, it's one opening bracket `(` at the beginning to much, but at the end it's the same ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
if((isset($_POST['ms']) && isset($_POST['ws']))
        || (isset($_POST['mc'])&&isset($_POST['ws']))
        || (isset($_POST['md'])&&isset($_POST['ws']))
        || (isset($_POST['ms'])&&isset($_POST['wc']))
        || (isset($_POST['ms'])&&isset($_POST['wd']))
        || (isset($_POST['mc'])&&isset($_POST['wc']))
        || (isset($_POST['mc'])&&isset($_POST['wd']))
        || (isset($_POST['md'])&&isset($_POST['wd']))
    )){

      $error_message .=('You can only play as one sex! <br />');
  }


if((isset($_POST['mc']) && isset($_POST['md'])){ //***

    $error_message .=('You cannot play in both the cadet tournament and mens doubles <br />');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

the first `(` in second if must be removed

```
if( isset($_POST['mc']) && isset($_POST['md']) ){ //***
    $error_message .=('You cannot play in both the cadet tournament and mens doubles <br />');
}
```